# Question about how to calculate a certain residue

Tags: residue-calculus

I want to calculate the residue at $z=i$ for $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2+1)(z^2+9)(z^4+4)}$.

I've calculated the residue correctly by using the formula $Res(f;i)=\lim_{z\to i}{(z-i)f(z)}$.

I also know that it is possible to use the formula:
$Res(f;i)=\frac{P(i)}{Q'(i)}=\frac{1}{D((z^2+1)(z^2+9)(z^4+4))|_{z=i}}$

But in the solution to the problem the following calculation is done:

$Res(f;i)=\frac{1}{(z^2+9)(z^4+4)D(z^2+1)|_{z=i}}$

Greatful if anyone can show me how this formula follows from the other two formulas, or give me another explanation to why it works.

Comment: What is $D$? Is it a function or a number?

Comment: It's the differentiation operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use $P(z) = \frac{1}{(z^2+9)(z^4+4)}$ and $Q(z) = z^2+1$.

Comment: Ah, yes! Thanks!